# Maven plugin for updating Eclipse annotation processor settings?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and have a Maven project which uses an annotation processor to generate code.

I have set up annotation processing in the project properties (in Eclipse), but ideally I'd prefer this IDE setting to be managed by Maven so I can share it easily with my colleagues.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maven you'll need to specify [annotationProcessors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessors) in the maven-compiler-plugin configuration. Though I don't think [current JDT integration](http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/src/org/eclipse/m2e/jdt/internal/JavaProjectConversionParticipant.java) for m2eclipse is currently processing this configuration parameter and you may want to open an [enhancement request](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/support/) for that.